# How to package a net-beans java project for Ubuntu

Tags: software-center, application-development, java, oracle

I'm in final year of my b.tech, for project I have created an multilingual dictionary in Java (net beans 6.7.1) in which we can search words meaning, its synonyms, antonyms and an example, or if its not available than can add new word in data base.

I have used swing , oracle data base 10g for words storage and external jar rs2xml which is not provided by oracle by default, I have many more ideas in my mind which I will apply on this project after my finals.

Now I want to publish it on Ubuntu Software Center as an open source project so others can also share new ideas and make it successful.

I have no idea how to convert **net-beans java project into a debian package**.

Is there any criteria that needs to be fulfill in order to publish your project on software Center?

Please help and explain each and every step clearly like how to backup database table and check if user have java or oracle installed on his computer or prompt him to install these first etc.

Comment: oracle database is an over kill for simple apps like dictionary , you can use sqlite database

Answer (score 0):

You can pakage it as per debian packaging guidelines , here is the [documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/Java/Packaging)